# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.

Tags: android-studio-3.2

Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:androidApis'.
Failed to transform file 'android.jar' to match attributes {artifactType=android-mockable-jar, returnDefaultValues=false} using transform MockableJarTransform

Comment: You should read this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: have the same problem
```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.
        at proguard.Initializer.execute(Initializer.java:485)
        at proguard.ProGuard.initialize(ProGuard.java:271)
        at proguard.ProGuard.execute(ProGuard.java:113)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.BaseProguardAction.runProguard(BaseProguardAction.java:64)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.doMinification(ProGuardTransform.java:262)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.ProGuardTransform.acce
```

Answer (score -2):

compileSdkVersion 28
Sync success